# Java Spring: Attribute 'time-unit' is not allowed to appear in element 'int:poller'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-integration

I am using Java Spring Integration version 2.0.0 and Java Spring Framework 3.0.5

I am getting the error "Attribute 'time-unit' is not allowed to appear in element 'int:poller'." in my configuration xml files, and this is causing big problems for my program. I am thinking this may be a version issue, but I am not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-2.0.xsd">


<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="file:${dir.cu}"
channel="cuProvinceFilesIn" prevent-duplicates="true" filename-regex=".+\.csv">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="60" time-unit="SECONDS" max-messages-per-poll="10" receive-timeout="10000">
    </int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: check your classpath for duplicate spring int jars of differing versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why don't use more fresh version of the framework? http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/

From other side I guess it's just an issue of your Eclipse IDE, because as we know the `time-unit` is there in the `<poller>` [element](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/2.0.x/spring-integration-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/config/xml/spring-integration-2.0.xsd#L1217).

Try to apply `Spring nature` for the Eclipse and almost verything should go away.

From other side you always can result in any `time-unit` the `milliseconds` (by default):

```
<int:poller fixed-delay="60000">
```

Comment: I am enhancing a project which was already created a few years ago, so changing the technology is not in my best interest.

Comment: At a minimum, you should upgrade to the latest 2.0.x release (2.0.6) to get bug fixes, but it __would__ be in your best interest to move to something much more recent.